# DataFrame - ValueError: Unexpected tuple with StructType

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a manual schema for a `dataframe`.  The data I am passing in is an RDD created from `json`.  Here is my initial data:

```
json2 = sc.parallelize(['{"name": "mission", "pandas": {"attributes": "[0.4, 0.5]", "pt": "giant", "id": "1", "zip": "94110", "happy": "True"}}'])
```

Then here is how schema is specified:

```
schema = StructType(fields=[
    StructField(
        name='name',
        dataType=StringType(),
        nullable=True
    ),
    StructField(
        name='pandas',
        dataType=ArrayType(
            StructType(
                fields=[
                    StructField(
                        name='id',
                        dataType=StringType(),
                        nullable=False
                    ),
                    StructField(
                        name='zip',
                        dataType=StringType(),
                        nullable=True
                    ),
                    StructField(
                        name='pt',
                        dataType=StringType(),
                        nullable=True
                    ),
                    StructField(
                        name='happy',
                        dataType=BooleanType(),
                        nullable=False
                    ),
                    StructField(
                        name='attributes',
                        dataType=ArrayType(
                            elementType=DoubleType(),
                            containsNull=False
                        ),
                        nullable=True

                    )
                ]
            ),
            containsNull=True
        ),
        nullable=True
    )
])
```

When I use `sqlContext.createDataFrame(json2, schema)` and then try to do a `show()` on the resulting `dataframe` I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected tuple '{"name": "mission", "pandas": {"attributes": "[0.4, 0.5]", "pt": "giant", "id": "1", "zip": "94110", "happy": "True"}}' with StructType
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `json2` is just a `RDD[String]`. Spark has no special knowledge about serialization format used to encode the data. Moreover it expects a `RDD` or `Row` or some product and it is clearly not the case.

In Scala you could use

```
sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rdd)
```

with `RDD[String]` but there are two problems:

- this approach is not directly accessible in PySpark
- even if it was schema you've created is simply invalid:

  - `pandas` is a `struct` not and `array`
  - `pandas.happy` is not a `string` a `boolean`
  - `pandas.attributes` is `string` not `array`

Schema is used only to avoid type inference a not for type casting or any other transformations. If you want to transform data you'll have to parse it first:

```
def parse(s: str) -> Row:
    return ...

rdd.map(parse).toDF(schema)
```

Assuming that the you have JSON like this (fixed types):

```
{"name": "mission", "pandas": {"attributes": [0.4, 0.5], "pt": "giant", "id": "1", "zip": "94110", "happy": true}}
```

correct schema would look as follows

```
StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("pandas", StructType([
        StructField("attributes", ArrayType(DoubleType(), True), True),
        StructField("happy", BooleanType(), True),
        StructField("id", StringType(), True),
        StructField("pt", StringType(), True),
        StructField("zip", StringType(), True))],
    True)])
```

Comment: I made them all strings because of an example on the Databricks website, so I can easily change them back.  How do you create an Array Type (nested struct) in Pyspark?

Comment: Nested struct is not `ArrayType`. Nested struct is just struct. And struct is simply product type (tuple / Row). Array is array (list).

Comment: Makes sense, I'm trying to convert over from Scala without knowing a whole lot of Scala.